# protobuf.js: Is there a synchronous way of loading static code

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I've trying to load synchronously protobuf.js static code (generated with pbjs).

According to the [documentation](http://dcode.io/protobuf.js/#pbjs-for-javascript), the documented method is asynchronous.

### The asynchronous loading is done like that:

```
protobuf.load("bundle.json", function(err, root) {
    ...
});
```

As my further code should only be executed after loading is done, I believe synchronous loading would be better.

Is there any way to load it synchronous or is there any tweak to get that done?

Comment: Asynchronous does not mean that you cannot make your code execute after it's loaded...

Comment: I assume you mean that to continue with my code in the callback, because it will require the protobuf's to be loaded?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's how asynchrony works.

Comment: This would not be a unrecommended approach as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protobuf.js has a [synchronous loading method](http://dcode.io/protobuf.js/Root.html#loadSync)

You can totally achieve what you want with asynchronous loading.
Just put your further code in the callback, or don't add a callback and add your further code to the .then method of the returned Promise.

Comment: link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

protobuf.js can load synchronously with `loadSync`. Follows example code

```
const protoPath = __dirname + "/proto"

const files = (fs.readdirSync(protoPath))
  .filter(file => file.split('.').pop() === 'proto')

const root: protobuf.Root = protobuf.loadSync(files)
```